# Filter a Dataframe on a column, if a list value is contained in the column value. Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, filter

I am familiar with filtering a dataframe if the value of a column can be found in a list, but I can't figure out how to implement the reverse case, iterating through values in a list to see if those values are contained in the column value.

For example, my df has a column with values like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column':['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'abc, def', 'ghi, jkl', 'abc']})


     column
0       abc
1       def
2       ghi
3  abc, def
4  ghi, jkl
5       abc
```

Note that all values are strings, including values like `'abc, def'`

I also have a list of two values I want to filter by: `filter_list = ['abc', 'jkl']` so that I keep these values where they are found in the df column.

I want to filter the dataframe column if the value in the list is contained in the column, such that the final output in this case would be `'column' = ['abc', 'abc, def', 'ghi, jkl', 'abc']`

```
     column
0       abc
1  abc, def
2  ghi, jkl
3       abc
```

I want to keep the rows where "abc"/"jkl" are contained.

My first thinking was using list comprehension in a lambda function, but that throws an error:

`dataframe = dataframe[dataframe['column'].apply(labmda x: f for f in filter_list in x])]`

Note I cannot use the `.isin()` method because that wont capture the complex strings like `'abc, def'`

Looking for thought's on how to do this. I cannot use the re package. I only have access to pandas/numpy.

**UPDATE:**

Big thank you to Balaji! The working solution:

keeping list values:

`dataframe[pd.notna(dataframe[column]) & dataframe[column].astype(str).str.contains('|'.join(filter_list))]`

filtering out:

`dataframe[pd.notna(dataframe[column]) & ~dataframe[column].astype(str).str.contains('|'.join(filter_list))]`

Comment: you can use `str.contains` or `.isin` if you split on your string delimiter. i.e `df[col].str.split(',',expand=True).stack().isin(your_list)` will return a True/False bool

Comment: I did this: `dataframe = dataframe[dataframe['column'].str.split(',',expand=True).stack().isin(filter_list)]` and received this error: `ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'column':['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'abc, def', 'ghi, jkl', 'abc']})
contains_filter = '|'.join(filter_list)
df = df[pd.notna(df.column) & df.column.str.contains(contains_filter)]
```

Output:

```
     column
0       abc
3  abc, def
4  ghi, jkl
5       abc
```

Comment: Filter list is a variable, so like this: `filter_list = filter_list = '|'.join([f for f in filter_list])` ? Doing that, at least, throws this error: `TypeError: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [str]`

Comment: I got the same error after adjusting the code to this: `filter_list = '|'.join(filter_list)`

Comment: @Whitewater I'm not making use of `isin`. See my post. It makes use of `contains`. Please see my post again.

Comment: Updates: ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values -- UPDATE: It works for columns where there are no nan values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218440/discussion-between-balaji-ambresh-and-whitewater).

Answer (score 1):

`str,contains` is the usual way to go, but lets look at an alternate method. We can use `.stack` and `isin` if your string column is separated by commas.

```
filter_list = ['abc', 'jkl']

s = df['column'].str.split(',',expand=True).stack().str.strip()

df_filter = df.loc[s[s.isin(filter_list)].index.get_level_values(0)]

print(df_filter)

     column
0       abc
3  abc, def
4  ghi, jkl
5       abc
```